# How to read the result for matchTemplate (OpenCV2 in python)

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, template-matching

The following code is actually the result which of which I immediately print out:

```
result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
```

Picture size:

- haystack_img = 27x16
- needle_img = 7x7

However, I don't really understand what that means.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output gives you a **response** image that will be of size 21 x 10 where the 7 x 7 `needle_img` template is slide across the image left to right and top to bottom where each 7 x 7 window coincident with the template is extracted and a correlation is computed.  Note the reduction in size for the output. It's smaller than the search image because the template is assumed to fit completely inside the image.

However, the metric you've chosen is a *distance* metric (`cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED`).  For each element in this response image, it gives you the dissimilarity between the template and each window.  The location that gives you the smallest value means that if you placed the template's top left corner at this location, this is where the template best matches the image.

Here is some code that will draw a bounding box where the template best matched in the haystack image:

```py
result = cv2.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
top_left = min_loc
w, h = (7, 7)
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
img_to_show = haystack_img.copy()
cv2.rectangle(img_to_show, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
cv2.imshow("Result", img_to_show)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Run the template matching, then use `cv2.minMaxLoc` to find the smallest and largest values as well as where they're located in the image.  We want to use the location of the smallest value given the method you're using (distance). `min_loc` will provide the column and row coordinates of the top left corner of where the template should best match.  We create the bottom right coordinates based on the dimensions of the template, then create a new copy of the image and draw a white rectangle on that showing you were the template best matched then show the image at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @rayryeng's reply and a little bit more explain is that~

Result:

- Position (0,0) is with 0.05779364 confident
- Position (0,1) is with  0.03569747 confident

Picture size:

- haystack_img = 27x16
- needle_img = 7x7

Since the image is compared by every pixel so the X and Y position can be counted as

- X:27-7+1) = 21
- Y:(16-7+1) = 10

X:0, 1, 2, 3, ... ,21 = the position in every list
also equal to

```
len(result[0])
```

[

```
0.05779364
0.06816062
0.07974802
0.09858147
0.12885822
0.16065261
0.19880965
0.28301606
0.3753051
0.47798595
0.5469872
0.5558993
0.5515625
0.5280534
0.51457506
0.4536102
0.41659155
0.38783583
0.37042123
0.34466013
0.31110483
```

]

Y:0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 = the position in the list also equal to

```
len(result)
```

[

```
[0.05779364 0.06816062 ...]
[0.03569747 0.03553726 ...]
[0.06887697 0.07845661 ...]
[0.10796931 0.12338859 ...]
[0.15996848 0.18395858 ...]
[0.224204   0.2505653 ...]
[0.3423201  0.37836382 ...]
[0.38187546 0.38226286 ...]
[0.39126304 0.39931965 ...]
[0.39757547 0.4197682 ...]
```

]

Offical docs:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be